# How to cut short long strings while rendering using Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm sorry for asking a very stupid question. It should be very easy but I'm not able to do this. I'm creating a minimal working model on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b8xe7d). So, I've a string array containing some information about me (say). I want to display them one by one using `ngFor`. But there will be some elements whose strings are very long.

For eg: The string is:

> Apple, Ball, Cat, Dog, Elephant, Fish, Goat, Hen, Ink, Jackal, Kite

The displayed text should be:

> Apple, Ball ...

That means after the second comma `,` or may be after certain characters, say 15 characters, it should be `...` because the original text is occupying a large width.

I tried these methods:

1. slice(start, end)
2. substring(start, end)
3. substr(start, length)

But these methods will permanently cut short the text. I don't want that. Hope I was able to explain the problem. Please correct me. Here's the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b8xe7d).

Comment: have to tried angular pipe

Comment: @KiranMistry, I'm trying it out separately but not able to achieve the goal exactly. Can you please help me. I'm following this doc: https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Comment: check i posted answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can derive your own pipe `EllipsisPipe` from `SlicePipe`. In the code below, the derived pipe calls `super.transform` to apply `slice:0:maxLength`, and appends the ellipsis if the original string is longer than `maxLength`. Please note that `super` refers to the parent class `SlicePipe`.

```
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { SlicePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
  name: 'ellipsis'
})
export class EllipsisPipe extends SlicePipe {
  constructor () {
    super();
  }
  transform(value: string, maxLength: number): any {
    const suffix = value && value.length > maxLength ? "..." : "";
    return super.transform(value, 0, maxLength) + suffix;    
  }
}
```

The pipe can then be used in the template:

```
{{ token | ellipsis:15 }}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-pipe-example-2mpnbg?file=src%2Fpipes%2Fellipsis.pipe.ts) for a demo.

---

**Update**

If the items are displayed inside a PrimeNG [Chips](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/chips) component, you can define a custom template and apply the `EllipsePipe` in the template:

```
<p-chips [(ngModel)]="values">
  <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
    {{item | ellipsis:15}}
  </ng-template>
</p-chips>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v8yp86?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.

Comment: This solved my problem. Can you please explain a little bit because I'll have to explain this to my tech lead when I put the same in the actual project. Thanks.

Comment: I added some explanations to the answer.

Comment: Hi ConnorsFan, I've one last question. There's a slight change. In place of `li` tag now we've primeng chips `<p-chips [(ngModel)]="tokens"></p-chips>` Then how do I use pipe with this kind of code.

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz with this new requirement? That situation appears to be very different.

Comment: Here's a new stackblitz, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f7ud4f

Comment: I'm also trying with you but no success yet. I've read the documentation also. Please let me know if you do it first. :-)

Comment: I updated the answer with an example for PrimeNG Chips. See the new stackblitz

Answer (score 1):

Two way to truncate text into angular.

```
let str = 'How to truncate text in angular';
```

**1. Solution**

```
{{str | slice:0:6}}
```

Output:

```
how to
```

If you want to append any text after slice string like

```
 {{ (str.length>6)? (str | slice:0:6)+'..':(str) }}
```

Output:

```
how to...
```

**2. Solution(Create custom pipe)**

if you want to create custom truncate pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
 name: 'truncate'
})

export class TruncatePipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(value: string, args: string[]): string {
    const limit = args.length > 0 ? parseInt(args[0], 10) : 20;
    const trail = args.length > 1 ? args[1] : '...';
    return value.length > limit ? value.substring(0, limit) + trail : value;
   }
}
```

In Markup

```
{{ str | truncate:[20] }} // or 
{{ str | truncate:[20, '...'] }} // or
```

Don't forget to add a module entry.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TruncatePipe
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here is stackblitz [You can check here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-apitiw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

---

## Different way using css

---

```css
.b {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 60px;  /* you can do with the help of width  */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
}
```

```html
<div class="b">Hello world!</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your help Kiran. But the answer I accepted is less complex and more easy to implement. Thanks a lot for the solution. :-)

Comment: Hi Kiran, can you please look into this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f7ud4f
Here the condition is slightly different. Instead of using `li` tag and `ngFor`, here I'm using `ngModel` inside primeNg `chips`.